# Building a calendar for iphone

Tags: iphone

I am building an application for the iPhone that will display upcoming and past events. I settled for a list view, but then I realized that a calendar would be a best match

However, the iPhone Human Interface Guidelines just mentions the Date Picker, not the calendar, so I believe there is nothing like that out of the box. Is that true? If so, does anyone know of a third-party control that could be used? (I could write one myself, but I'd rather pick up something ready, since this is a departure on the original project plans).
Hey guys plz help me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t used it myself but maybe [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) fits your needs.